# Bootstrap 3 tooltip shifts right cell - is this a bug?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

If one assigns Bootstrap 3 tooltip to table cells. When tooltip is shown, the right cell of tooltipped cell is shifted one place to right. Is this bug or sth else?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-toggle="tooltip" title="AAA titl">AAA</th>
      <th data-toggle="tooltip" title="BBB title">BBB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this code in js

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

and this to your `<th>` tag

```
data-container="body"
```

check out the snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-toggle="tooltip" title="AAA titl" data-container="body">AAA</th>
      <th data-toggle="tooltip" title="BBB title">BBB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this helps. But, is this a bug in Bootstrap or what!?

Comment: no it's not a bug  container Appends the tooltip to a specific element. Example: container: 'body'. This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to position the tooltip in the flow of the document near the triggering element - which will prevent the tooltip from floating away from the triggering element during a window resize.